# Is it possible to write the following equation in matrix form?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Is it possible to write the following formula into matrix form?

$\omega_i=\sum_{j=1}^nA_{ij}\sin(\theta_j-\theta_i)$

Comment: As it has been proposed, $\omega_{i}$ corresponds to the sum of $i$-th row from the matrix given by

$$m_{ij} := A_{ij}\sin(\theta_{j} - \theta_{i})$$

But the range of $i$ has not been specified though.

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia the range of $i$ is from 1 to n

Comment: then you are dealing with a square matrix.

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia I don't understand. The left-hand side of the equation $\omega_i$ constitutes a vector with dimension $n\times 1$. It looks like the dimension of the $m_{ij}$ matrix you proposed is $n\times n$ which does not match $n \times 1$. Did I make something wrong? Could you explicitly write it in matrix form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use the well-known formula: $sin(x-y) = sin(x)cos(y)-sin(y)cos(x)$ to rewrite the OP's expression into the following form:

$$\omega_{i} = cos(\theta_i) \sum_{j=1}^nA_{ij}sin(\theta_j)-sin(\theta_i) \sum_{j=1}^nA_{ij}cos(\theta_j)$$

This way we have obtained an expression for the elements of the vector $\omega$ in terms of two matrix products. I assume this is what the OP was looking for.